# Expected value of type string and private key too short errors

Tags: contract-development, nft, testing, private-key, error

I got stuck with hardhat config. My .env looks like this:
API_URL="https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/T4w-Ys... my API URL..."
PRIVATE_KEY="b285d...my private key..."

and hardhat.config.js is:

```
/**
* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
*/
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' });
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.0",
  defaultNetwork: "ropsten",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    ropsten: {
      url: API_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
    }
  },
}
```

When I run npx hardhat compile, I get these errors:

```
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.ropsten.url - Expected a value of type string.
  * Invalid account: #0 for network: ropsten - private key too short, expected 32 bytes
```

Can someone help me please what the problem could be?

Comment: try to add the privte key and url directly in the config. if it works then you are not using dotenv correctly and it cannot get the values from enviroment variables correctly

Answer (score 1):

I come into almost the same problem.
It is the problem with **using dotenv**, as Majd TL commented above.
I change it to the following code and it works.

```
require("dotenv").config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.1",
  defaultNetwork: "ropsten",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    ropsten: {
      url: API_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
    }
  }
};
```

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: using none "0x" PRIVATE_KEY solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Removing "0x" in front of the PRIVATE_KEY solved my problem

```
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      url: API_URL,
      accounts: [`${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .env file is named `.env` only and not `process.env`. To do this on Mac via Terminal use `mv process.env .env`. The file will now be hidden so you must also show hidden files and folders to view it in Finder.